# My Application doesn't appear in Play market after a day?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I'm facing an strange issue that I didn't have before.

Yesterday, I uploaded .apk file of my application in Play market. I filled all required fields of form and published it under alpha testing. My application has limited to just Australia.

Then I created a community in Google+ and invited my testers.

Then I added this community to my alpha testers under "Manage list of testers".

Then I shared the link that was provided by system to my testers.

Following screen displays when I click the link.

[image]

There is another link at bottom of screen "Download from the Play store" (In this format: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[PACKAGE-NAME-OF-APPLICATION]). Page not found displays when I click it :(

[image]

I don't think propagation of application on Google servers takes so much time and 30 hours is more than so much!!! Appearing of my old applications took 2-5 hours.

What you think? any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you find a solution (or reason of problem), you think how stupid I am!!!

As you can see in image, I thought that "became a tester" is banner. But it was a button.
So after I confirmed i'm tester and clicked provided link then I could see the page.